# load data infile mysql how to ignore not valid records inserting

Tags: sql, mysql, load-data-infile

I have a text file and want to load it to my db table using load data infile, but this file contains invalid values, that contain empty strings, how to ignore this lines?

Answer (score 0):

edit your text file first to search-and-replace the invalid values.  *Then* load the data into mysql.